# Tridion and SOLR Configuration

Tags: solr, configuration, content-management-system, field, tridion

Hi I am using Tridion CMS and have configuration with SOLR, however, I would like to add new fields. I have added new fields in Tridion, but they are not being configured properly in SOLR, is there a step that I might be missing when configuring the new fields? If possible, is there a walkthrough of the necessary steps to make sure that the new fields are being configured between Tridion and SOLR properly?

Comment: Hi Samantha, did you know there is a Stackexchange forum specifically for questions about Tridion? See https://tridion.stackexchange.com/. If you post your question there, you have a better chance of getting some answers.